# Call Balancer Vault Swap failure

Tags: defi, balancer

I tried to use Balancer Vault Swap in my smart contract.

```
function swap() external payable returns (uint256 wstETHAmount) {
    uint256 amount = msg.value;
    IBalancerRouter.SingleSwap memory singleSwap = IBalancerRouter.SingleSwap({
        poolId: 0x36bf227d6bac96e2ab1ebb5492ecec69c691943f000200000000000000000316,
        kind: IBalancerRouter.SwapKind.GIVEN_IN,
        assetIn: IAsset(address(0)),
        assetOut: IAsset(wstETH),
        amount: amount,
        userData: bytes("")
    });

    IBalancerRouter.FundManagement memory funds = IBalancerRouter.FundManagement({
        sender: msg.sender,
        fromInternalBalance: false,
        recipient: payable(msg.sender),
        toInternalBalance: false
    });

    uint256 amountOut = amount * _getPrice() / 1e18;
    uint256 limit = 999 * amountOut / 1000;
    uint256 deadline = block.timestamp + 5 minutes;
    //console.log(address(this).balance);
    wstETHAmount = IBalancerRouter(BalancerVault).swap(singleSwap, funds, limit, deadline);
    
}
```

And i wrote foundry tests for it, but in my case it was failed.
[image]
Can anyone help me with this problem？